# c++ class inheritance error C2509

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

i have two classes
first:
.h file

```
 #ifndef Vandenynas_H
#define Vandenynas_H
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "skaicioti.h"
using namespace std;

class Vandenynas {
public:
    void danne (int i,int a, int a0);
    void getdan();
    string GetName ();
};
#endif
```

.cppfile

```
  #include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "Vandenynas.h"

skaicioti::v vektorV;
void Vandenynas::danne(int i,int a, int a0)
{ 
    switch (i)
    {
        case 0:
            vektorV.x=a-a0;
            break;
        case 1:
            vektorV.y=a-a0;
            break;
        default:
            vektorV.z=a-a0;
            break;
    }
}
```

second:
.h file

```
    #ifndef Zuvis_H
#define Zuvis_H
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "Vandenynas.h"
class Zuvis:public Vandenynas
{
public:
    void plaukti();
};
#endif
```

.cpp file

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#include "Zuvis.h"
skaicioti::v vektorZ;
void Zuvis::plaukti()
{
    cout<<"plaukia\n";
}
void Zuvis::danne (int i,int a, int a0)
{
        switch (i)
    {
        case 0:
            vektorZ.x=a-a0;
            break;
        case 1:
            vektorZ.y=a-a0;
            break;
        default:
            vektorZ.z=a-a0;
            break;
    }
}
```

and when i compile i get error:
zuvis.cpp(14) : error C2509: 'danne' : member function not declared in 'Zuvis'
maybe someone can tell me where is my mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need the following:

1. `danne` should be virtual,
2. `danne` should be declared in the header of the class `Zuvis`.

---

```
class Vandenynas
{
public:
    virtual void danne (int i,int a, int a0);
    void getdan();
    string GetName ();
};

class Zuvis : public Vandenynas
{
public:
    void plaukti();
    virtual void danne (int i,int a, int a0);
};
```

The problem is that (1) if you don't declare `danne` as virtual in the base class, you won't be able to present alternative implementation in the derived class (that is, *override* it), and (2) if you are going to override the function in the derived class, you should say that already at the point of class declaration.

Alternately, you might want to just overload the function in the derived class. For that case, you don't need `virtual` in both cases (though you still need to declare the function in the `Zuvis`'s header). That way your function *hides* the function with the same name in the base class, and doesn't *override* it.

The difference between hiding and overriding can be seen here:

```
Vandenynas* pv = new Zuvis();
pv -> danne(0, 0, 0); // (*)
```

The line marked `(*)` executes `Vandenynas`'s implementation of `danne` in the case of hiding, and `Zuvis`'s implementation in case of override. Do you see?

Comment: so where is point of inheritance of classe, i can just make two seperate methots in this classes
where is difference?

Comment: @Edgar: I've just added this to the answer :-) See the example at the bottom.

Comment: @Edgar: inheritance means that you can _call_ the base class' function if you have an instance of the derived class, even if you _don't_ override/hide is in the derived class. The function is just _inherited_.